# Magento 2.0: How to override the .phtml in vendor>magento>module-theme>view>frontent>templates>html

Tags: magento-2.0

I already made a structure app>design>frontend>  > . 
What structure do I need to make do override the .phtml in vendor>magento>module-theme>view>frontent>templates>html

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-theme-in-magento-2-part-2/

Answer (score 4):

You should do as below

Copy templates need to make override in:

`app/code/Magento/<module_name>/view/frontend/templates`

Location contain templates using to override:

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_<module_name>/templates`

**Example**

You want override  a template in:
`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

You create a file have path as:
`app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93472/magento-2-editing-module-structure-and-functions) is the right answer

Copy templates need to make override in:

```
vendor/magento/<module_name>/view/frontend/templates
```

Location contain templates using to override:

```
 app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_<module_name>/templates
```

Example

You want override a template in: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

You create a file have path as:     `app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`