# Magento 2 - editing module structure and functions

Tags: php, module, layout, magento2, theme

in Magento 1.x you could duplicate the extensions to `app/design/frontend/themeName/default/template/or/layout` and then modify it's layout or functionality via xml or phtml files.

How do we duplicate and edit certain modules now in M2? I have looked over the docs but couldn't find this info. For example i wish to edit phtml of `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml` correct way by having theme based module overwrite and now edit core modules within `vendor/magento*/` folder.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should view at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91588/magento-2-0-how-to-override-the-phtml-in-vendormagentomodule-themeviewfron/91593#91593 . But you need change path of theme

Comment: if you want overwrite file in core. copy file  with structure same in core pass into app/design.

Comment: Thank you both, exactly what i needed. Biil, can you pass that with an answer so i can mark it as correct?

Comment: Ok. I reply again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With version 2.0.0 release(not Github), You should do as below

Copy templates need to make override in:

`vendor/magento/<module_name>/view/frontend/templates`

Location contain templates using to override:

`app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_<module_name>/templates`

**Example**

You want override a template in: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

You create a file have path as: `app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Theme>/<name_theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`